# Command + Delete shortcut on windows 10

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a mac user for a quite a while now.

The most used shortcut I use is command (or windows key) + delete.
That deletes the whole line. But whenever I switch to windows, command + delete doesn't work.

Anything similar to that shortcut? I have done a simple google search, but it involves pressing a bunch of other keys as well.

Comment: It depends on what application you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the cursor to the start of the line by hitting the <kbd>HOME</kbd> key, then hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> Arrow to select the entire line and just hit DEL by itself.  This will remove the entire line, and move the next one up.  Not a single shortcut, but simple enough once you get the hang of it.

In some apps, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> clears the line to the right after the cursor position.
So if you put it at the start of the line, it will clear all of it, but does not remove the line - it will leave it blank.